# complex excel table lookup returning value in row below

Tags: excel, match, z-index

I have a complex excel table lookup formula that I need help with. I have tried creating an index match match formula but this needs to look up on the same row, not using column headings in the match formula. Essentially need pull a number based on two parameters from the attached sample table. I'll just throw out an example to make the most sense.

Example 1

Parameter 1: B010, Parameter 2: 60.3

Based on the table I would need the formula to pull in 0.05

B010 part is pretty simple. 60.3 is greater than 60 so it goes to the column with 60.6. And the formula needs to pull in the number BELOW the number that it finds in the row. Result = 0.05 [image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k9XIz.png)

Example 2

Parameter 1: B010, Parameter 2: 45, result: 0.075

Example 3

Parameter 1: B012, Parameter 2: 65, result: 0.033

Is this even possible to do in excel?

```
B010 48.5 51.6 54.3 57.3 60 60.6 61.1 61.8 62.3 62.8 
     0.075 0.07 0.065 0.634 0.055 0.05 0.045 0.04 0.035 0.033 
B012 48.5 51.6 54.3 57.3 60 60.6 61.1 61.8 62.3 62.8 
     0.075 0.07 0.065 0.06 0.055 0.05 0.045 0.04 0.035 0.033 
B013 48.5 51.6 54.3 57.3 60 60.6 61.1 61.8 62.3 62.8 
     0.075 0.07 0.065 0.06 0.055 0.05 0.045 0.04 0.035 0.033 
H010 48.5 51.6 54.3 57.3 60 61 62.1 63 64 64.9 
     0.065 0.06 0.055 0.05 0.045 0.042 0.04 0.038 0.035 0.033 
H020 48.5 51.6 54.3 57.3 60 61.6 63.1 64.6 66.3 67.7 
     0.125 0.119 0.113 0.107 0.105 0.1 0.095 0.09 0.085 0.08
```

Answer (score 0):

Enter as an array formula (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>):

```
=INDEX(B1:K10,MATCH(N2,A1:A10,0)+1,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(B1:K10,MATCH(N2,A1:A10,0),)>N3,0))
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Would have never gotten that far. It appears that the formula is returning the next higher number in the B010 row for example, it actually needs to select the number below that number, in the row below like in the image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/k9XIz.png For example, rather than returning 60.6, it needs to return 0.05.  Is that possible?

Comment: @DebraS Of course. Sorry. I didn't read your question quite closely enough. I've updated the answer.